# Combining Spring Data query builder with Spring Data JPA Specifications?

Tags: jpa, spring-data, specifications, query-builder

Spring Data allows you to declare methods like findByLastname() in your repository interface and it generates the queries from the method name automatically for you.

**Is it possible to somehow have these automatically-generated queries also accept a Specification, so that additional restrictions can be made on the data before it's returned?**

That way, I could for example call findByLastname("Ted", isGovernmentWorker()), which would find all users that have the last name Ted AND who satisfy the isGovernmentWorker() specification.

I need this because I'd like the automated query creation provided by Spring Data *and* because I still need to be able to apply arbitrary specifications at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such feature. Specifications can only be applied on [JpaSpecificationExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) operations.

**Update**
The data access operations are generated by a proxy. Thus if we want to group the operations (as in findByName + Criteria) in a single SELECT call, the proxy must understand and support this kind of usage; which it does not.

The intended usage, when employing Specification API would look like this for your case:

```
findAll(Specifications.where(hasLastName("Ted")).and(isGovernmentWorker())
```

Comment: Right. But is there a way to somehow simulate the same thing? For example, you can create a wrapper around findAll(Specification s) to simulate findOne(Specification s).

Comment: Manish - thanks. Yes, going full-on specifications definitely works - I was just hoping that I could also make use of the query builder functionality Spring Data has. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spring data allows you to implement custom repository and use Specifications or QueryDSL.

Please see [this](http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) article.

So at the end you will have one `YourCustomerRepository` and appropriate `YourRepositoryImpl` implementation, where you will put your `findByLastname("Ted", isGovernmentWorker())` method.
And then `YourRepository` should extend `YourCustomerRepository` interface.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. The QueryDSL is just syntactic sugar. I want to be able to run a query like findByLastname("Ted", isGovernmentWorker()). Can you show me what syntax I'd need to use. I don't think there is such a solution.